# Browser not updating the ReactJs code, showing old output which is not present in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, browser

It is a JavaScript file.

In browser console, it is showing old output data but their is no "console.log()" present in my whole code. It is present 2-3 days before but not at present.

In file: Analytics.actions.js their is no console.log(data) present, but it is showing in output

[image: In file: Analytics.actions.js their is no console.log(data) present, but it is showing in output]

Tried to clear cookies and cache data but it doesn't worked. Also same problem in incognito mode and edge browser.

Analytics.actions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

// const rootUrl = 'http://localhost:4000';
const rootUrl = '';

export const getAnalytics = () => async(dispatch)=> {
    try {

    dispatch({
        type: 'GetAnalyticsRequest'
    })


    const {data} = await axios.get(`${rootUrl}/api/v1/analytics/getAll`, {
        withCredentials: true
    })


    console.log('test');

    dispatch({
        type: 'GetAnalyticsSuccess',
        payload: data
    })
        
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'GetAnalyticsFailure',
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}

export const getUrlAnalytics = (hash) => async(dispatch)=> {
    try {

    dispatch({
        type: 'GetUrlAnalyticsRequest'
    })


    const {data} = await axios.get(`${rootUrl}/api/v1/analytics/url/${hash}`, {
        withCredentials: true
    })

    dispatch({
        type: 'GetUrlAnalyticsSuccess',
        payload: data
    })
        
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'GetUrlAnalyticsFailure',
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}

export const getClicks = (hash, duration) => async(dispatch)=> {
    try{
        dispatch({
            type: 'GetClicksRequest'
        })

        let url = "";

        if(duration && hash){
            url = `${rootUrl}/api/v1/analytics/clicks?hash=${hash}&duration=${duration}`
        }
        if(duration && !hash){
            url = `${rootUrl}/api/v1/analytics/clicks?duration=${duration}`
        }
        if(!duration && hash){
            url = `${rootUrl}/api/v1/analytics/clicks?hash=${hash}`
        }
        if(!duration && !hash){
            url = `${rootUrl}/api/v1/analytics/clicks`
        }

        const {data} = await axios.get(url, {
            withCredentials: true
        })
        dispatch({
            type: 'GetClicksSuccess',
            payload: data
        })
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type: 'GetClicksFailure',
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code but, can you try to add console.log('test') in that file ? see if you see two console.log

Comment: Added the code and tried console.log("test") in getAnalytics  function but not getting it in console it just showing that data

Comment: So if you are working on a some local development environment like webpack-dev-server. Try to kill the server and re-run it. You probably tried that but yeah can't say much at this point.

Comment: Yes, tried re running the react app and it some time worked correctly, but how it is showing output of code which I have written 2-3 days before, because it is not present anywhere in code now. Also tried this code on GitPod.io (cloud) but same problem

Answer (score 0):

In my backend server file, the below code is present which is rendering the previously generated build folder.

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend/build")));
 app.get("*", (req,res)=>{
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../frontend/build/index.html"));
 });
```

That's why it is showing some output of previous code.